# Credentials set on azure pipeline for Android tests

Tags: azure, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, azure-pipelines

I have some Android tests in Jetpack Compose UI testing. I have set them on a azure pipeline to be run and used Gradle task with task "connectedAndroidTest".
The first test is to login the user (microsoft login).
My question is how to set the credentials as pipeline variables and use them in that test instead of setting them in test data class in the code

Comment: you can save your secure variable in 'Variable groups' which locate at 'Pipelines -> Library'

Comment: I work from the UI on azure pipeline, where can I set that $(var) in the Gradle task form the UI?

Comment: @vasutalexandru, I have updated my answer based on your update. Hope it can resolve your query.

Comment: Still does now work, I have to mention I am using connectedAndroidTest command in gradle task to run instrumentation tests and not unit tests and it is on windows

Comment: System.getenv does it not read the variables from the mobile device and not the pipeline or local machine..in my case laptop because i use selfhosted agent

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Based on the requirement to use classic pipeline for Gradle test, since the `Gradle` task in classic editor doesn't support `Environment variables` feature at the moment, you may add a `bash` task to [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job) the secret value of another variable `PipelineTestPWD` as the value of variable `TestPWD` into environment for downstream Gradle task to use. Please make sure the variable name in your test code and the script is in uppercase.

```
String inputPassword = System.getenv("TESTPWD"); // Get the value of the environment variable, whose name should be in uppercase
```

**bash**

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TESTPWD]$PIPELINETESTPWD"
```

[image]

---

Based on your requirement to retrieve pipeline variable value for your tests without hardcoding the values in the test class data, you may try and add `env` properties of the `Gradle` task. Here is a unit test sample `testPasswordValidation` for your reference. It supports secret variable values as well.

```
package ms.appcenter.sampleapp.android;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPasswordValidation() {
        String expectedPassword = "Password1234";
        String inputPassword = System.getenv("TestPWD"); // Get the value of the environment variable
        assertEquals(expectedPassword, inputPassword);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I work from the UI on azure pipeline, where can I set that $(var) in the Gradle task form the UI?

Comment: Still does now work, I have to mention I am using connectedAndroidTest command in gradle task to run instrumentation tests and not unit tests and it is on windows

Answer (score 0):

Found a way because using System.getenv(varname) will actually look for env variables on the mobile device for mobile tests and not pipeline or local env.

1. Set variables on pipeline
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzESJ.png
2. Add arguments for the task field in Gradle task ":app:connectedAndroidTest -PMY_USERNAME=$(MY_USERNAME) -PMY_PASSWORD=$(MY_PASSWORD)"..I added :app: for mine because I have multiple modules and it takes a lot if I don't mention the exact one
3. Add in build.gradle in defaultconfig get project property and define a buildconfig field to be able to access that variable.

   ```
    val username = if (project.hasProperty("MY_USERNAME")) project.property("MY_USERNAME") else "noUsername"
    val password = if (project.hasProperty("MY_PASSWORD")) project.property("MY_PASSWORD") else "noPassword"

    buildConfigField("String", "MY_USERNAME", "\"$username\"")
    buildConfigField("String", "MY_PASSWORD", "\"$password\"")
   ```
4. Sync the project and after run in terminal from Android Studio "./gradlew assembleDebug" in order to update BuildConfig with the new values
5. Assign to which variable you want to have value from pipeline BuildConfig.MY_USERNAME and BuildConfig.MY_PASSWORD...make sure to import from correct package BuildConfig(the one where you added to the build.gradle)